# Display the image on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery-plugins

How to display the image on a fullcalendar to a date(if the event is exist)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to add an image in each an every Event,with respect to the url related to that event, Yes its possible, You just need to edit few line in the fullcalender.min.js /and the calender.css file.Just go through the code and edit where the event design is create, if any problem just ask. Then I will give you the solution.